# How can I get the difference between two values in list

Tags: python, list, set, set-difference

I'm trying to get the difference between temp1 and temp2 which will be *10.25.60.156 and 10.22.17.180* . Since the data in temp2 has brackets I've been receiving this error:

```
z = set(temp1).symmetric_difference(set(temp2))
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

. 
    How can I get the difference between these two with one containing a bracket? Thanks in advance!

```
temp1 = ['10.25.39.70', '10.25.16.160', '10.25.60.156']
temp2 = [['10.25.16.160'], ['10.22.17.180'], ['10.25.39.70']]

z = set(temp1).symmetric_difference(set(temp2))
print(z)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
temp1 = ['10.25.39.70', '10.25.16.160', '10.25.60.156']
temp2 = [['10.25.16.160'], ['10.22.17.180'], ['10.25.39.70']]

print( set(temp1).symmetric_difference(v[0] for v in temp2) )
```

Prints:

```
{'10.22.17.180', '10.25.60.156'}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! What a life saver!

Answer (score 0):

Why do the elements of temp2 need to be lists? If they do, you could use list comprehension to select the 0th element of temp2 when comparing:

```
temp1 = ['10.25.39.70', '10.25.16.160', '10.25.60.156']
temp2 = [['10.25.16.160'], ['10.22.17.180'], ['10.25.39.70']]

z = set(temp1).symmetric_difference(set([x[0] for x in temp2))
print(z)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check if this will work for you:

```
temp1 = ['10.25.39.70', '10.25.16.160', '10.25.60.156']
temp2 = [['10.25.16.160'], ['10.22.17.180'], ['10.25.39.70']]

temp2= [item for sublist in temp2 for item in sublist]
print(set(temp1).symmetric_difference(temp2))
```

Answer: {'10.22.17.180', '10.25.60.156'}